# Sort posts according to a numeric value entered with ACF

Tags: loop

I've tried a little bit of everything, but I still can't find the right solution.

I need to sort my posts according to a numeric value that is entered in each post. I'm using the following PHP code, but it's not working:

```
$args['meta_query'] = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'key',
        'type' => 'numeric',
    )
);
```

I also tried this code:

```
$args['meta_key'] = 'costo_attrazioni_ridotti_18_25';
```

Then of course I have these other values in the args as well:

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'meta_key' = 'costo_attrazioni_ridotti_18_25',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'paged' => $paged,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ($the_query->have_posts()):
    while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post();?>
        ...
    endwhile;
endif; unset($the_query); wp_reset_query();
```

How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/405505/edit) to show the complete `$args` and how you're using it—are you using `new WP_Query( $args );`? How are you including the meta key/value in the `$args`?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question as requested